# What is the difference between signing and partial signing a transaction?

Tags: transactions, signature

The [Transaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html) class has a [sign](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html#partialSign) and [partialSign](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html#sign) method. What are the differences between them and what are the different use cases of using `partialSign` over `sign`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a bunch more digging, and I think the real difference is that `sign` updates `this.signers` on the transaction, while `partialSign` does not. In practice that means that calling `sign` invalidates previous signatures, while calling `partialSign` does not.

You can see this in the source code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/194d2d1/src/transaction.ts#L620

The `sign` and `partialSign` functions are the same, except that `sign` contains:

```
this.signatures = uniqueSigners.map(signer => ({
  signature: null,
  publicKey: signer.publicKey,
}));
```

I've made an example which is based on the cookbook example, but hopefully a bit clearer: https://replit.com/@mcintyre94/sign-partial-sign#index.js

If you run this as-is it should work, with output similar to:

```
Setup complete!
Created the transaction, signed by Bob
Recovered the transaction as Alice
Signed the transaction as Alice
serialized te transaction
Sent transaction 5x25WynLSyN7Dyufj7FgkK7jkvLjf2L4FJpvwkQK38gNiRU4HmY4ZrtE2ZwNEt7CfAsa9tLoccbiMk19wEJY2ho1
Confirmed transaction 5x25WynLSyN7Dyufj7FgkK7jkvLjf2L4FJpvwkQK38gNiRU4HmY4ZrtE2ZwNEt7CfAsa9tLoccbiMk19wEJY2ho1
```

It uses the same pattern: Bob signs first, then Alice, then the transaction is sent.

If you look at the `api` function you'll see that Bob is using `sign`:

```
  // Partial sign as Bob
  transaction.sign(bobKeypair);

  // Serialize the transaction and convert to base64 to return it
  const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({
    // We will need Alice to deserialize and sign the transaction
    requireAllSignatures: false,
  });

  const transactionBase64 = serializedTransaction.toString("base64");
  return transactionBase64;
```

It also works if that's changed to `partialSign`.

But Alice uses `partialSign`:

```
  // Recover the transaction by de-serializing it
  const recoveredTransaction = Transaction.from(
    Buffer.from(transactionBase64, "base64")
  );
  console.log('Recovered the transaction as Alice')

  // Partial sign it as Alice
  recoveredTransaction.partialSign(aliceKeypair)
  console.log('Signed the transaction as Alice')
```

If you update it so that Alice uses `sign` instead you'll get an error:

```
Setup complete!
Created the transaction, signed by Bob
Recovered the transaction as Alice
Signed the transaction as Alice
/home/runner/sign-partial-sign/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:3146
      throw new Error('Signature verification failed');
            ^

Error: Signature verification failed
    at Transaction.serialize (/home/runner/sign-partial-sign/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:3146:13)
    at file:///home/runner/sign-partial-sign/index.js:132:43
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

I think what's happening here is that `sign` updated `this.signers` and that invalidated Bob's signature.

This is also why the code Alice uses to send the transaction is really weird. You can't call `connection.sendTransaction(recoveredTransaction, [aliceKeypair])` because you'll get the verification error. I'm guessing this is because `sendTransaction` uses `sign` and thus invalidates Bob's signature.

I think this example is better than my cookbook one because it shows where you must use `partialSign`. Bob doesn't need to, Alice does.

Comment: hmm was thinking it would be possible for; Bob to partially sign and Alice signs the transaction.

Comment: Do you mean for Alice to sign with `sign` or with `partialSign`? `sign` will invalidate Bob's signature (even if Bob used `partialSign`), but Alice could use `partialSign` and that'd work.

See this fork of the REPL where Bob uses `partialSign` and Alice uses `sign`, it has the same signature verification error: https://replit.com/@mcintyre94/partial-sign-sign#index.js

Comment: Yup, I wasn't sure why Alice calling `sign` would invalidate Bob's signature if Bob signed with `partialSign`

Comment: I think it's because Alice's call to `sign` sets `this.signatures` on the transaction, and updating any field on the transaction invalidates previous signatures. In many cases that's ideal - you don't want someone changing the feePayer or fiddling with instructions after you've signed it. But in this use case you do want someone else to be able to sign it afterward, which they can do using `partialSign` which doesn't update `this.signers` and doesn't invalidate the previous signatures.

Comment: ahh ofcourse, I blocked out on the `this.signers` being updated. Thanks Callum!

Answer (score 4):

To discuss this, this we first need to talk about *offline transactions*.

There are 3 steps to submitting a transaction: 1) create the transaction, 2) sign it, and 3) broadcast it to the chain. In most cases, all three happen immediately one after another but strictly speaking, it does not have to!

For example, you can create a transaction and sign it, then send it to someone else to verify and submit it. A more interesting scenario is where you create and sign the transaction, serialise it and send it to a second party, who also has to sign it and then finally submit it to the chain.

[Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/offline-transactions.html#partial-sign-transaction) does mention some scenarios where this is useful:

> - Send an SPL token in return for payment
> - Sign a transaction so that you can later verify its authenticity
> - Call custom programs in a transaction that require your signature

Comment: I wrote that cookbook example and can elaborate a bit on the motivating use case for me. With Solana Pay transaction requests, you need to write an API that returns a serialized transaction that can be signed and broadcast by the user('s wallet). If you want that transaction to send something *back* to the user (like an NFT or an SPL token) then you need to partially sign it with the authority to do that, before returning it from that API.

Comment: That's awesome. Could you clarify; In the example you mentioned, is it possible for the merchant to `sign` the transaction AND have the user eventually `sign`? or can it only be partialSign + sign?

Comment: I've posted a separate answer, it ended up being way too detailed for a comment and includes a better example than the cookbook one. In short though, the merchant can `sign` or `partialSign`, the user must `partialSign` regardless which one the merchant did.

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive, @CallumM. I upvoted yours!

Answer (score 3):

Both `sign` and `partialSign` are used to add signatures to a transaction.

A transaction needs someone to pay the fee. In case the feePayer is not provided for a transaction then the first signer will be used for paying the fee.

`partialSign` is used to add signatures to a transaction. For instance if you are using `createAccount` then you need to make sure the new account is also a signer.

Here's an example of using `partialSign`

```
let randomKey = SolanaKeypair.generate();

let programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID;

let associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID;

const associatedToken = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(randomKey.publicKey,phantomPublicKey,false,programId,associatedTokenProgramId);
    const recentBH = await connection?.getRecentBlockhash();

let t = new Transaction({
      feePayer: phantomPublicKey,
      recentBlockhash: recentBH.blockhash
    })
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: phantomPublicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: randomKey.publicKey,
      space: MintLayout.span,
      lamports: await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection),
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    ,
    createInitializeMintInstruction(
      randomKey.publicKey,
      7,
      phantomPublicKey,
      phantomPublicKey,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    )
    )
    .add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        phantomPublicKey,
          associatedToken,
          phantomPublicKey,
          randomKey.publicKey,
          programId,
          associatedTokenProgramId
      )
  ).add(
    createMintToInstruction(
      randomKey.publicKey,
        associatedToken,
        phantomPublicKey,
        67000000000,
        [],
        programId
    ));
    
    
    const sendT = await providerSolana.signTransaction(t); // This triggers Phantom wallet so that user can sign transaction

sendT.partialSign(randomKey);  // This adds the randomKey signature which will be the new Mint

    const fsignature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(sendT.serialize());
```